# pytorch train function Varibles and Tensors (read my introduction i dont know my problem as well it just dont work )

Tags: python, variables, pytorch, tensor, mnist

I started learning pytorch and started with videos about MNIST handwriting and learnt it with an video but the video is 2 years old and some things have changen since then i guess because it dosent work as in the video and i seriously dont know anything so i dont know whats my error or what i do wrong i just type everything the dude says in the video and want to understand and learn it this way(maybe you know better ways how to learn machine learning/deep learning would appreciate it) my code looks like this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim
import os
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True}
train_data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.MNIST('data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,),(0.3081,))])),
                                                    batch_size=64, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

test_data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(datasets.MNIST('data', train=False, transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,),(0.3081,))])),
                                                    batch_size=64, shuffle=True, **kwargs)
```

above everything works like in the video and i find the data in an folder now comes the class and it doesnt looks like theres an error but i dont know.

```
class Netz(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Netz, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, kernel_size= 4)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size= 4)
        self.conv_dropout = nn.Dropout2d() 
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 60)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(60, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 4)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.conv_dropout(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 4)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(x.size())
        exit()


model = Netz()
model.cuda()
```

something with this Varibale function is wrong it just dont works and pycharm also shows me there has to be something wrong but i dont know what so i ask here maybe you can help i also googled abit about it and it looks like this varible thing got removed or so but i dont know what to write else

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.8)
def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(train_data):
        data = data.cuda()
        target = target.cuda()
        data = Variable(data)
        target = Variable(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out = model(data)
        criterion = F.nll_loss
        loss = criterion(out, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

for epoch in range(1, 30):
    train(epoch)
```

the error code looks like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\mnist handwriting.py", line 60, in <module>
    train(epoch)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\mnist handwriting.py", line 46, in train
    for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(train_data):
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 279, in __iter__
    return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 719, in __init__
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 46, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 761, in _try_get_data
    data = self._data_queue.get(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\queue.py", line 178, in get
    raise Empty
_queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Finnw/PycharmProjects/pytorch 3.7/mnist handwriting.py", line 60, in <module>
    train(epoch)
  File "C:/Users/Finnw/PycharmProjects/pytorch 3.7/mnist handwriting.py", line 46, in train
    for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(train_data):
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 345, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 841, in _next_data
    idx, data = self._get_data()
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 798, in _get_data
    success, data = self._try_get_data()
  File "C:\Users\Finnw\PycharmProjects\pytorch 3.7\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 774, in _try_get_data
    raise RuntimeError('DataLoader worker (pid(s) {}) exited unexpectedly'.format(pids_str))
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 10444) exited unexpectedly

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe just setting num_workers to zero would solve your problem. One other thing that would solve your problem is to place your code in a main function.

The reasons for this can be found here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming . The reason for this is that num_workers tells PyTorch to generate data samples in a multithreaded way, launching num_workers threads, such that they can be served as fast as possible to your training loop.

The error code you gave actually tells you pretty much the same thing:

```
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...
```

Comment: yea putting the workers too zero solved my problem thanks

Comment: @FinnWiechert Then if the problem is solved, don't forget to accept and thumbs up the answer :) .